# redirect a download link from multiple subdomains to another using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I want to redirect all download links of different subdomains to another main subdomain, for example:

```
https://sub1.example.com/folder/file.pdf
https://sub2.example.com/folder/file.pdf
```

these links should be redirected to:

```
https://mainsub.example.com/folder/file.pdf
```

the links should stay the same, only the part of the subdomain should be changed.
is there an easy way to do that by writing an htaccess for each subdomain?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick: the idea is to change the subdomain only and leave the rest of the query intact. You don't need one .htaccess per subdomain - this one can cover all of them.

In this example, a **subdomain is required** - calling `https://example.com/folder/file.pdf` will have no effect.

There is also an exception for `www.example.com` - note the exclamation mark (exclusion)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mainsub.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you want to restrict the rule to file downloads only, then you can complete the expression but you need to determine the possible patterns for `/folder/file.pdf`